# Sbt multiple projects with commons

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project with 4 modules and one common module which should be added to every jar file. However, it is configured in the build.sbt in parent module

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(P1, Commons, P2, P3, P4)

lazy val Commons = (project in file("commons"))

lazy val P1 = (project in file("p1"))
  .dependsOn(Commons)
```

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2018.03 as build

ARG SCALA_VERSION
ARG SBT_VERSION
ARG JAVA_VERSION

RUN yum install -y java-${JAVA_VERSION}-openjdk-devel
RUN yum install -y https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/${SCALA_VERSION}/scala-${SCALA_VERSION}.rpm
RUN yum install -y https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm

WORKDIR root/P1

ADD ./project/plugins.sbt project/
ADD ./project/build.properties project/
ADD build.sbt .
RUN sbt update

COPY . .

RUN sbt clean assembly

RUN cp target/scala-2.12/P1-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar P1.jar

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY --from=build \
   root/P1/P1.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/P1.jar"]
```

However, when I am creating dockerfile for each of the P1, P2, P3, P4 it doesn't include the added Commons. How am I supposed to do that? Should I change anything in my build.sbt files in every project?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace "aggregate" with "dependsOn" ?
Aggregate means the task you are running will also run on aggregated projects which is not what you expect.

edit : "aggregate" is useful to run tests on each sub-module for example while running a "sbt clean test" on root project

Comment: it is different case. For example when I want to update my projects, all I am going to do is do sbt update in the root folder, which will invoke all of it in my subfolders. The problem is with dependsOn being specified in the root folder, which I should have speccified in the project folder, because of docker.

Comment: OK. Both aggregate and dependsOn are cumulative, so you may try something like :

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(P1, P2, P3, P4)
  .aggregate(P1, Commons, P2, P3, P4)

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem of having dockerfile in project P1, and in that project configuration(build.sbt file) there is nothing specified of commons folder. Therefore docker has no idea whether it should include commons folder or not.

Comment: Which plugins are you using ? How do you run your build ? Did you try something like "sbt P1/docker" ?

Comment: I am using it in docker, I have updated my question. I have no idea, how should I include this commons in dockerfile

Comment: Thank you Ajris it's more clear to me. You can try "RUN sbt clean P1/assembly". You'll also have to adapt the "RUN cp" instruction to seek the assembly jar in "P1/target/".